# Google Mail Like IMAP (Web) Application

Tags: email, web, imap, web-applications, google

I'm looking for an IMAP web frontend (or client application) that has the features and speed of Google Mail minus the ads and privacy concerns. Most important are simple user interface, fast search speed even on large boxes and the conversation style view. Has anyone recommendations?

ciao,
Elmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how full featured your looking,  but you have you tried [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/).  Very full featured and powerfull (maybe more than your looking for), and has an open source edition.

Comment: Last time I looked into Zimbra, it was basically only available as a full-on replacement for your entire email system.  Is it possible to use just the web frontend without messing with the existing backend?

Comment: Still looks that way, I'm currently downloading have a gig worth of software. I report back with more details when I've configure it.

Comment: It provides the features (search is a little slow though), but requires that you use the supplied IMAP server (maybe that can be reconfigured) and dozens of other services.

Comment: I've never implemented Zimbra before, so I can't comment on the server side.  But I have used it as an end user and found it very good.  But I will be curious to here how you find it @eweber

Comment: @Sam: The user interface was very nice. Highly customizable and responsive (they use the Yahoo UI framework). The admin interface made most tasks also very easy.

However, and that is the reason why I did not use it, it requires to use the whole stack and the stack is not very friendly with regard to integrate it into existing services. Makes it hard to solve a specific problem. 

Since I have some free time on my hand I've decided to create my own interface. Back-end part (indexing, conversations) works, now I'm just adding the UI.

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked at [roundcube](http://roundcube.net/)?

Comment: Didn't know that one, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: If you need something a little more advanced I've had great success with Zimbra.

Comment: +1, we're using roundcube - it's very slick, clean and stable.

Comment: This looks quite interesting.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I checked it out, very good web app, but it currently lacks the features I'm looking for. The search does only work on one folder by default and the full search plug-in is a hack to set up and then the performance lacks. Also there is no conversation view. I'll definitely check back at the project from time to time to see if it has made progress.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check out [Squirrel Mail](http://squirrelmail.org/), it's a free web IMAP client.  There are lots of plugins that can be added to it, and it looks like development has been continuing.

Comment: SquirrelMail I checked out, but search performance and the interface were not very good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of different OpenSource Webmail that you can implement to replace Gmail compatible with IMAP:

- Roundcube
- RainLoop
- Zimbra
- AfterLogic
- MailPile
- Squirrelmail
- CuttleFish
- MailSlurper
- Mailur
- SOGo
- Libremail